# Android toolbar menu Xamarin Forms custom renderer [NOT RESOLVED]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

I am new to custom renderers and can only do basic things like customizing entries, pickers etc. I am really trying to implement an android toolbar menu into my navbar on x.forms and I know I will need to do this through a custom renderer.

I just really do not know where to start. It has proven difficult to find what I need online so I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

What I want is something that looks like this:
[image]

Which simply drops down and presents a list of options. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it on iOS then all you need to do is:

```
<ToolbarItem Title="title" Order="Secondary"/>
```

If you need it on iOS then even Custom Renderer won't help you.

Comment: I saw this during my searches, I do not think it works for Xamarin 4.0+ with AppShell because it does not show an overflow menu. It simply shows the items. Can you confirm please?

Comment: Do you know the iOS equivalent? As in what they use instead, or what the common practice for that is? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As lvan said, if you want to implement this like picture, you just add ToolbarItem for ContentPage.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem
        Name="MenuItem1"
        Order="Secondary"
        Priority="0"
        Text="Item 1" />
    <ToolbarItem
        Name="MenuItem2"
        Order="Secondary"
        Priority="1"
        Text="Item 2" />

</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

You don't need to custom render.

[image]

You can take a look the following article for more info.

https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/

Comment: I saw that website when I was trying to make this work, like I replied to Evan above, I do not think this works for Xamarin.Forms Shell. Maybe I am doing something wrong but I tried it and it shows the full item names.

Comment: @Do you want to add toolbaritem in xamarin.forms shell? If yes, I suggest you can use menu item in shell, you can take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout

Comment: Thanks, but thats involving a flyout and is entirely different from what my question is asking. I simply stopped using Xamarin Forms Shell for now, the menu item (on the navigation bar) issue is currently open and I believe Microsoft is actively working on it.

Comment: @steve, **I simply stopped using Xamarin Forms Shell for now, the menu item (on the navigation bar) issue is currently open and I believe Microsoft is actively working on it.** I am not sure what you say, you mean that this feature that you require , Microsoft is working?